# Issue with elm/html style attribute package in new 0.19 project

Tags: package, elm

I noticed that while working through some build errors in a new Elm 0.19 project that I started seeing errors such as the following when running elm-make.

> 50|         [ iframe [ src "https://fakeurl.com", height "0", width
>   "0", style [ ( "display", "none" ), ( "visibility", "hidden" ) ],
>   sandbox "" ]
>
> This `style` call produces:
>
> ```
> String -> Attribute msg
> ```
>
> But all the previous elements in the list are:
>
> ```
> Attribute msg
> ```
>
> Hint: Everything in the list needs to be the same type of value. This
>   way you never run into unexpected values partway through. To mix
>   different types in a single list, create a "union type" as described
>   in: http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html

The direct error after this states:

> This argument is a list of type:
>
> ```
> List ( String, String )
> ```
>
> But `style` needs the 1st argument to be:
>
> ```
> String
> ```

From what I can tell the use of the style attribute on the line where elm-make is complaining seems to be the expected usage *for recent more recent versions of elm/html*.

Ex.

```
style [ ( "display", "none" ), ( "visibility", "hidden" ) ]
```

Looking a bit deeper it looks like I have elm/html 1.0.0 package installed wheras the latest for Elm 0.19 is 2.0.0. Even more strange is that the version of elm/html for .19 called 1.0.0 seems to be more like a copy of the elm/html package for 0.18 that was called ~version 5.0.0~ and these all have the newer signature that takes a list. Looking at the actual package that is installed under `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\elm\0.19.0\package\elm\html\1.0.0\src\Html` I do indeed see that the signature is `style : String -> String -> Attribute msg` which from what I understand should only be for the elm/html package 1.0.0 version for Elm 0.18. Based on this I can only conclude that I have 0.18 packages in my elm/0.19.0 package repository folder.

Is my logic above sound or is there another explanation? How did it get this way, perhaps I did something wrong? Is this a known issue with one of the tools? How do I resolve this issue for my project so I can move forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you got confused by transfer of core packages to `elm/` namespace in Elm 0.19. Packages in `elm-lang/` namespace are for Elm 0.18. Latest version of `elm/html` is 1.0.0 whereas for `elm-lang/html` it is 2.0.0. With that said it is correct you are having `elm/html` 1.0.0 and correct signature for `style` is `String -> String -> Attribute msg`.

This particular change is mentioned in [release notes for 0.19](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md). Sadly, there are other changes which are not on that document so ping people on Slack if you run into other troubles.

Comment: Looking closer at the project namespaces now to understand. From what I can see so far is that I must have gotten thrown off by looking at some other package by accident. Perhaps http instead html and just not being careful enough to catch the difference. From what I can see it looks like the newest version of elm/html for Elm 0.19 takes the signature you described. So I'll probably have to do some hand conversion on the results from html-to-elm.

Comment: @jpierson check out [elm-upgrade](https://github.com/avh4/elm-upgrade). It does conversion of `Html.Attributes.style` usages automatically. And also plenty of other stuff.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I was able to automate this a bit using `elm-format  --upgrade`. Glad I found this before trying to do it all by hand, it's a bit html file that I'm starting with.